# Python Flask user login redirection

Tags: python, redirect, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have build a very simple user login system without a database, but the redirection is a problem again. If the submitted username & password from the html file is correct then python is doing the following thing:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        attempted_username = request.form['username']
        attempted_password = request.form['password']

        if attempted_username == 'admin' and attempted_password == 'password':
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            error='E-Mail or Password not available'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Now the URL becomes the following one: `shost/index` and Chrome tells me then

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
The DNS address of the shost server couldnt be found.
```

Why isn't the URL becoming the `server_IP/index`, e.g. `127.0.0.1/index`, because this one works in my browser. How can I prevent flask issue the `shost` ?

Here is also the html form code for the login:

```
<form class="text-left" method="post" action="">
    <input class="mb0" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{request.form.username}}"/>
    <input class="mb0" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{request.form.password}}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/> 
</form>
```

The `@app.route("/index")` section of the code looks as follows:

```
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Many thanks and best regards

Comment: please include the rest of the `login_page` and the `index` route.

Comment: @edgaromar90 thanks for the feedback. I added the form code.

Comment: I think i know what your problem is. Let me see the `@app.route("/index")` section of your code.

Comment: You have not added the `action` attribute in the `form` tag . `action` should be the url where you want to go after login . If you want to go to `index` then there should be `action="/index" ` in the respective form tag.

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez added the code section. @ 0decimal0 I am redirecting the user from the server side, after the login data was compared if its true

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are rendering the page for the login, you are only telling python to generate the index page if POST is used, but POST hasn't been used because no form has been completed yet. In addition in the return redirect(url_for('index')) you would need to add the 'app.' .

Try something like this.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        attempted_username = request.form['username']
        attempted_password = request.form['password']

        if attempted_username == 'admin' and attempted_password == 'password':
            return redirect(url_for('app.index'))

    return render_template('loginpage.html')
```

Comment: Edited the post. I use redering